# Regular expression dealing with property address & grouping

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a little issue with a regex query.

I'm attempting to parse an address from a string into separate variables. My Regex is below.

(?<streetAddress>(?<number>[\d]+)(?<subNumber>[A-Za-z?])|(?<number>[\d]+)[/]?(?<subNumber>[A-Za-z0-9]))\s(?<street>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*)

I need to sperate a adress into

1. StreetNumber
2. SubNumber
3. StreetName

I managed to get the below variations working:

- **60B Goldberg street**
- StreetNumber = 60B
- Number = 60
- SubNumver = B
- StreetName = Goldberg street
- **12/a Salisbury rd**
- StreetNumber = 12/a
- Number = 12
- SubNumber = a
- StreetName = Salisbury rd
- **12/2 Salisbury rd**
- StreetNumber = 12/2
- Number = 12
- SubNumber = 2
- StreetName = Salisbury rd

The one I'm struggling with is when an address has a subnumber greater than 9.

- **20/12 Salisbury rd**
- StreetNumber = 12
- number = 1
- SubNumber = 2
- StreetName = Salisbury rd

I can't seem to isolate the first number as the street number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the language you are in?

Comment: Oh sorry, thought I tagged that c#

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a plus after `?<subNumber>[A-Za-z0-9]`

```
(?<streetAddress>(?<number>[\d]+)(?<subNumber>[A-Za-z?])|(?<number>[\d]+)[/]?(?<subNumber>[A-Za-z0-9]+))\s(?<street>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*)
```

However just a note, using regex for street addresses might be like hitting a moving target, ie there are so many possible combinations and formatting i doubt you'll ever get a consistent result

Comment: You're completely correct about the address and being a moving target. Thankfully it's limited because I"m pulling the information back from an API that keeps a semi-consistent format. Unfortunately for me, they don't expose them as sperate values. Which would be really helpful. 

Thanks for your help. Needed another set of eyes :)